# Nachgestellte Spezifikationen in Firmennamen

Tags: spelling, proper-noun

Viele Firmennamen enthalten nachgestellte Spezifikationen über die Art der Firma, z. B.:

> Müller Maschinenwerke
>   Octothorpe Bürobedarf
>   Schmidt Müllpressen

Derartige Ergänzungen werden und wurden durch ein Leerzeichen abgegrenzt (und zwar lange, bevor Marketingmenschen das Deppenleerzeichen erfanden), was auch verständlich ist, liegt hier ja etwas anderes als eine normale Zusammensetzung vor (»Gestern lieferte uns die Firma Schmidt Müllpressen zwei ihrer weltbekannten Schmidt-Müllpressen.«). Allerdings bin ich daran gescheitert, hierzu **irgendeine offizielle Rechtschreibregel** oder auch nur **Privatmeinung irgendeiner Wörterbuchredaktion** zu finden. Gibt es hierzu wirklich nichts oder war ich einfach nur blind?

Answer (score 6):

Nach den [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/) ist folgende Vorgehensweise empfohlen:

#### [Substantivgruppen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf77-2)

> **§ 77** Zusätze oder Nachträge grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein.

So kann man mit erklärende Nachträgen in Firmenbezeichnungen wie folgt schreiben:

- *Die Firma Paddelino, Bootsverleih, hat den Steg am Baggersee renovieren lassen.*

Insbesondere bei Eigennamen **darf man das Komma aber auch weglassen**:

> **§ 78** Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.

Nach dieser Regel ist also auch folgende Schreibweise korrekt, wenn man *"Bootsverleih"* als nähere Bezeichnung des Eigennamens der Firma versteht:

- *Die Firma Paddelino Bootsverleih hat den Steg am Baggersee renovieren lassen.*

#### [Komposita aus Eigennamen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Bindestrich/pgf46-52.html)

Ganz anders ist die Regel aber, wenn ein Eigennamen Bestandteil eines Kompositums wird. Dann gilt:

> **§ 46** Man setzt einen Bindestrich in Zusammensetzungen, die als zweiten Bestandteil einen Eigennamen enthalten oder die aus zwei Eigennamen bestehen.

Demnach muss im folgenden Beispiel ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden:

- *Der Paddelino-Bootsverleih wird heute seinen neuen Steg einweihen.*

*Anmerkung:* Nach §77 und §78 sind aber auch folgende Varianten richtig (*"Firma"* ist Feminin):

- *Paddelino, Bootsverleih, wird heute ihren neuen Steg einweihen.*
- *Padellino Bootsverleih wird heute ihren neuen Steg einweihen.*

#### [Individuelle Kreationen](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=Kreationen&service=canooNet)

Natürlich darf man seinen Firmennamen frei gestalten, auch wenn er nicht nach gültigen Rechtschreibregeln gebildet wird (Beispiel: *"Müllermilch"*).

Comment: Die zitierten Regeln waren mir bekannt, aber unbefriedigend, zumal sie nicht mit passenden Beispielen versehen waren (von denen ich annehme, dass sie Dein Werk sind). Ich würde die Spezifikationen nicht als Zusatz einstufen, denn dann würden sie anders gesprochen. § 46 greift auch nicht, da hier nur der erste Bestandteil ein Eigenname ist. Bei *der Paddelino-Bootsverleih* wird durch den Artikel *Paddelino* zu einer Spezifikation von *Bootsverleih* und das Konstrukt ist ein anderes. *Müllermilch* unterscheidet sich von dem Gesuchten ebenfalls durch andere Aussprache sowie Untrennbarkeit.

Comment: Nebenbei bemerkt ist das Standardgeschlecht für Unternehmen Neutrum: »Mercedes, das im letzten Jahr Gewinn einfuhr, …« (Und das, obwohl Mercedes ursprünglich ein Frauenname war.)

Comment: Zum weiblichen Geschlecht eines Unternehmens passt auch, dass es ausschließlich Töchter produziert ;) *"Mercedes"* ist leider kein gutes Beispiel, weil das Unternehmen *"Daimler"* heißt und eine Aktiengesellschaft ist. Meine persönliche Meinung ist, dass man zwischen Paddelino und Bootsverleih entweder ein Komma oder einen Bindestrich setzen sollte, dafür ist zum Glück sogar noch eine Regel vorhanden :)

Comment: Heutzutage dürfen manche Leute immer noch *Schmidt* heißen, obwohl das eigentlich anders geschrieben wird.

Answer (score 0):

Dazu gibt es im Grunde nichts. Eigennamen kann jeder so gestalten, wie er will, und wenn er versucht, damit etwas auszudrücken, das wie etwas aussieht, wozu es eine Rechtschreibregelung gibt, er dies aber falsch macht, dann können wir ihn zwar alle auslachen, aber er kann zurücklachen, und wenn er will auch noch einen falschen Apostroph einbauen!

Es ist zwar unschön, und trägt zur zunehmenden Verkalkung der deutschen Sprache bei, aber Eigennamen haben sowas wie einen Rechtschreibschutz.

Komm, wir gucken uns ein paar Autos bei "Otto's Auto's um's Eck" an. (Als Konsequenz wird neuerdings das Genitiv 's nicht mehr als falsch bezeichnet, ich könnte kotzen! Mal sehen, wann das letzte bisschen Bildung nachgibt und den Rest auch anerkennt.)

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass Eigennamen einen besonderen (allgemeinen) Rechtschreibschutz genießen, nur dass in ihnen häufiger gegen die Regeln verstoßen wird und weniger Regeln zum Tragen kommen. Ein Rechtschreibfehler in einem Eigennamen hat die gleichen, geringen Konsequenzen wie anderswo auch. Mal abgesehen davon sind Rechtschreibregeln hierfür ja schon allein deswegen interessant, wenn man die Rechtschreibfehler anderer Leute eben nicht wiedergeben möchte, so werde ich z. B. immer *Lego* schreiben, auch wenn die Firma sich gerne *LEGO, lego* oder *Lєg0* geschrieben sähe.

Comment: Nur weil du den Namen dann anders schreiben würdest, so wie du ihn für richtig hälst, ist deine version nicht die richtige, und die Konsequenzen sind durchaus andere. Ein Rechtschreibfehler wird immer korrigiert werden, wenn möglich, z.B. überarbeitete Versionen von Büchern, Patches in Software, etc. Ein Betrieb dessen Name nicht rechtschreibkonform ist wird jedoch an allen Stellen mit diesem Fehler geführt werden, wenn er dies will. "Offizielle" Stellen werden gezwungen diesen mit falschem Namen wiederzugeben, genauso wie z.B. Werbeschilder etc.

Comment: »Ein Betrieb dessen Name nicht rechtschreibkonform ist wird jedoch an allen Stellen mit diesem Fehler geführt werden, wenn er dies will.« Wenn dies zuträfe, läsen wir täglich irgendwelche Firmennamen im Versalsatz oder komplett kleingeschrieben in Zeitungen. Die Wikipedia hat auch eine Richtlinie, Unternehmensnamen der gültigen Rechtschreibung anzupassen. [Hier](http://www.theslot.com/webnames.html) noch die Meinung eines Lektors dazu.

Comment: Für Eigennamen gelten im Allgemeinen amtliche Schreibungen. Für die hier gemeinten »amtlichen Schreibungen« ist nicht die »amtliche Rechtschreibung« (und auch nicht Duden oder Wahrig) zuständig, sondern: Amtliche Einträge für Personennamen enthalten die örtlichen Personenstandsbücher (ab 2009 Personenregister) beim Standesamt, die sogar amtlichen Hör- und Tippfehlern Gültigkeit verleihen. Amtlich sind Firmen- und Markennamen, wenn sie ins Handelsregister bzw. ins Markenregister beim Deutschen Patent- und Markenamt in München eingetragen sind.

Answer (score 0):

Eigennamen dienen der Identifikation. Das Ziel besteht damit in Unverwechselbarkeit bzw. Einmaligkeit. Gerade im Fall kommerzieller Namenssetzung wird auch im Bewußtsein, das Ideal nicht erreichen zu können, immer ein Bestreben vorliegen, auf bestimmte Art besonders und auffällig zu wirken.
    Naturgemäß steht dies im Widerspruch zur einer Vereinheitlichung, wie sie etwa als normierte Rechtschreibung in der Schriftsprache Ausdruck findet.

Ergänzend spielt im kommerziellen Bereich das Markenrecht hinein und die Anforderungen an schutzfähige Schrift- und Wortmarken - letzteres ist übrigens auch eine Erklärung für grammatikalisch und orthographisch fragwürdige bis falsche Konstruktionen wie häufig zu sehendes 'Deppen-Apostroph': Das Resultat mag nicht im Duden stehen, hebt sich aber vom Namen der Konkurrenz und gängiger alltagssprachlicher Formulierungen (die iirc grundsätzlich nicht markenschutzfähig sind) ab.

Insofern wäre für die Konstruktion von (Firmen-)Eigennamen eine offizielle Regelung bzw. ein Standard gerade nicht zu erwarten, soweit sie bzw. er über allgemeinsprachliche Regeln hinausreicht (die Unverwechselbarkeit einer auch zu sprechenden Wortmarke durch Verzicht auf alle Vokale in einer kanonischen Benennung herzustellen, wäre zB. wenig zielführend).