# Leerzeichen in Firmennamen

Tags: compound, brand-name

Über [Leerzeichen in Komposita](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita) wurde in SE schon vieles geschrieben. Meine Frage bezieht sich auf eine bestimmte Form von Firmennamen.

Es gibt an meinem Wohnort eine Privatschule, die sinngemäss "Müller Schulzentrum" heisst (Name geändert). Ein Satz aus der Website:

> Das Müller Schulzentrum ist die führende private Bildungsanbieterin.

Meinem Sprachgefühl kommt das falsch vor. Ist es wirklich falsch?

**Zusatzfrage:**

Ist es überhaupt richtig, einen solchen Firmennamen als Kompositum aufzufassen (d.h. ein Grundwort wird durch ein Bestimmungswort näher beschrieben), oder ist es eher eine Kurzform für etwas anderes? Beispiel:

> Müller-Pianos = Pianos vom Typ Müller ("Müller" beschreibt "Pianos" näher)
>
> Müller Pianos = Kurzform für "Spezialgeschäft für Pianos, Inhaber: A. Müller"

Comment: Das Phänomen ist nicht auf Privatschulen beschränkt: "Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz Universität Hannover". Siehe die Diskussion dazu hier unter "Namensgebung": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottfried_Wilhelm_Leibniz_Universit%C3%A4t_Hannover - Die Uni Hannover redet sich mit "das ist ein Eigenname, für den keine Regeln gelten" heraus und hat im Prinzip recht damit.

Comment: Die Uni Mainz leistet sich wenigstens einen Bindestrich und nennt sich "Johannes Gutenberg-Universität" - Es geht also praktisch alles.

Comment: Es gibt aber auch kein Gesetz, das verbietet, die Namen richtig zu schreiben. Und ich meine penetrant richtig zu schreiben.

Comment: Die zweite Frage ist ein Duplikat von: [Nachgestellte Spezifikationen in Firmennamen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/6617/2594)

Comment: Den Begriff des "Deppen-Leerzeichens" mag ich nicht und versuche ihn auch nicht zu verwenden. Nicht jeder, der ein Leerzeichen (oder auch einen Apostroph) irgendwohin schreibt, wo es nicht hingehört, ist automatisch gleich ein Depp.

Comment: Stimmt. Habe den Begriff "Deppen-Leerzeichens" aus der Frage entfernt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die deutschen Rechtschreibregeln schreiben eindeutig vor, wie Komposita mit Eigennamen zu schreiben sind:

> §50 Man setzt einen Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, deren erste Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen.

In den Beispielen wird dazu unter vielen anderen auch ein

> Johann-Sebastian-Bach-Gymnasium

aufgeführt.

Trotzdem gibt es - wie immer - auch viele Ausnahmen von der Regel, meistens dadurch begründet, dass die Gesamtbezeichnung ein Eigenname, eine "Marke" sei, die nicht den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln unterliege. Dies stimmt prinzipiell - die bekannte Marke "kinder Schokolade" unterwirft sich aus markenrechtlichen Gründen z.B. auch nicht dieser (es wäre nicht §50 anzuwenden) Regel und "darf" das auch.

Die *Johannes-Gutenberg Universität* in Mainz ist ein bekanntes Beispiel einer Bildungseinrichtung, die ihren Namen nicht nach gängigen Rechtschreibregeln bildet, die *Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz Universität Hannover* eine andere, die nach einer sehr lebhaften Diskussion 2006 ihren Namen bewußt entgegen der auch damals gültigen Rechtschreibregeln angenommen hat - mit folgender Begründung:

> „Das Präsidium der Leibniz Universität Hannover hat sich bewusst gegen Bindestriche zwischen den einzelnen Begriffen entschieden. Wir möchten die Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz Universität Hannover, kurz Leibniz Universität Hannover, als Marke etablieren. Der Verzicht auf Bindestriche erleichtert auch den Einsatz der Marke im internationalen Bereich. Dabei nehmen wir den Verstoß gegen die Rechtschreibregeln in Kauf.“

Ob sich ausgerechnet eine *Bildungseinrichtung* mit einem *Bildungsauftrag* so bewußt gegen gängige Rechtschreibung auflehnen und gerade bei einem so offensichtlichen Attribut wie ihrem Namen dagegen verstoßen sollte, ist sicher diskussionswürdig. (Genauso wie die Frage, was genau denn an Bindestrichen so "un-international" sein könnte)

Es ist allerdings tatsächlich so, daß der Name der Universität in seiner Gesamtheit einen Eigennamen darstellt, und damit keine grundsätzliche Bindung an die Regeln der Rechtschreibung besteht. Die Universitätsleitung bestimmt den Namen der Institution, damit ihren "korrekten Namen" und auch dessen lexikalischen Eintrag.

Eine Organisation oder Firma kann sich im Prinzip nennen, wie sie möchte - Wenn sie "Müller-Klaviere" oder "Müller Klaviere" oder gar "müllerKlawiere" heißen möchte, kann sie das tun. Ob das bewusste Verstoßen gegen Rechtschreibregeln in der Außenwirkung positiv oder negativ aufgenommen wird, kann sie nur selbst entscheiden. Ausgerechnet bei einer Schule würde ich allerdings eher von einer negativen Resonanz ausgehen (von einem Klavierbauer würde ich allerdings auch erwarten, dass er weiss, wie man das schreibt...).

Comment: Ich finde das Argument "als Marke etablieren" spannend. Woher kommt es eigentlich, dass ein Name, der Leerzeichen enthält, eher als Marke angesehen wird, als ein Name mit Bindestrichen? Bereits in Zeitungen aus den 1920er-Jahren habe ich Inserate gesehen, die für "Nivea Crème" warben. Hat das mit Typografie zu tun, wird der Bindestrich einfach als hässlich angesehen?

Comment: @wra Bei 1920er-Jahren wäre ich vorsichtig: Ich gaube, damals war das die "richtige Rechtschreibung", kann es aber momentan nicht beweisen.

Answer (score 1):

Unabhängig davon, ob die Struktur einem normalen Kompositum entspricht oder nicht:

- Ja, die Schreibung mit Leerzeichen gilt derzeit noch als falsch. (Dem steht allerdings entgegen, daß juristische Entitäten ihren eigenen offiziellen Namen selbst wählen und dabei nicht der Rechtschreibung verpflichtet sind. Wenn sich jemand "Lekker Bekker" nennen will, kann das Amt das nicht verbieten.)
- Nein, absehbar wird diese Regel nicht mehr durchsetzbar sein. Was früher das NDR-Sinfonieorchester war, nennt sich jetzt das "NDR Sinfonie Orchester", und ähnlich fast überall. Früher oder später werden sich diesem Gebrauch auch die Sprachwächter nicht verschließen können.